# Wrong output for sum of digits using loop c++

Tags: c++, loops, numbers, sum, output

i was required to make a program that asks users for a positive integer value, while the program uses loop to get the sum of all the numbers from 1 through n (user input). So lets say the user enters 5, the program would do 1+2+3+4+5 = 15

this is the code so far

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int number; int sum = 0;  // variables
    cout <<"Please input an integer greater than zero\n"
         <<"Please refrain from using a negative integer." <<endl;
    cin  >> number; // user input

  for (int i=1; i <= number; i++) // looping statement
      {
          sum = sum + i;     // formula that takes user digits and finds sum
      cout << sum;
      }
```

**My issue is that when i compile the program,for example, i enter 3, the program's output would be "136"**

i want it to say 1+2+3 = 6 or much something like "the sum of the integer is 6" i just want to show the total of the value. 
 I'm new in c++ any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `sum=number*(number+1)/2;` That´s all, aside from cin etc.

Comment: And with 3 as example: 1=1, 1+2=3, 1+2+3=6. You´re printing each partial result. But as said above: No loop necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing `cout << sum` *inside* your loop. That means you get one number output every time your loop runs (it's really writing `1` then `3` then `6` which gets all smushed together and comes out as `136`). Move that statement after the following `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can get your 1+2+3=6 output:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number; int sum = 0;  // variables
    cout <<"Please input an integer greater than zero\n"
         <<"Please refrain from using a negative integer." <<endl;
    cin  >> number; // user input

    for (int i=1; i <= number; i++) // looping statement
    {
        sum = sum + i;     // formula that takes user digits and finds sum
        if ( i == number ) 
            cout << i;
        else
            cout << i << "+";
    }

    cout << "=" << sum;
}
```